# Paste text into application behind my WPF app

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'm creating a WPF application where the user can click on a symbol and the app will paste that symbol into the application behind it (for example, into a web browser's text box or a Word document).

I'm having trouble with being able to remove the focus of my WPF app, so that when I use SendKeys, the symbol will be pasted into the other application. I am using the following code so far, but I don't want the window to hide, just be unfocused.

```
Clipboard.SetText("{symbol}")
Hide()
Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("^v")
Show()
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of control holds the "symbol"? Is the symbol text of some sort of image?

Comment: @Mary yes, the symbol is just text